# Cleaning up repetitive code with macros?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following queries and as can be seen, they require quite a lot of copy/pasting.

Is there a quick and elegant way to solve this with meta-programming?

```
def by_day_of_week(query \\ Conversation) do
    from c in query,
    select: %{
      monday:    fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = 0 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      tuesday:   fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = 1 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      wednesday: fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = 2 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      thursday:  fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = 3 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      friday:    fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = 4 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      saturday:  fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = 5 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      sunday:    fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = 6 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
    }
  end

  def by_time_of_day(query \\ Conversation) do
    from c in query,
    select: %{
      "00" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 0 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "01" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 1 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "02" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 2 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "03" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 3 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "04" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 4 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "05" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 5 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "06" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 6 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "07" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 7 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "08" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 8 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "09" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 9 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "10" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 10 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "11" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 11 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
      "12" => fragment("count(extract(h FROM ?) = 12 OR null)", c.inserted_at),
    }
  end
```

Comment: What attempts did you have for approaching this problem? Could you share them along with problems you've faced?

Comment: Have you tried generating that map with another function? I think you should be able to solve able to solve that problem without macros but if you insist on using them you can do that. ${} is just a function. Type in the iex quote do %{whatever}

Comment: The `fragment` method is not available outside the scope of `from`

Comment: @Tarlen then wrap whole from in macro and you'll be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Untested and ugly, but I'd say something like:

```
def days_of_week do
  days = ~w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)a

  for {day, index} <- Enum.with_index(days) do
    {day, quote do fragment("count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)", c.inserted_at, unquote(index)) end}
  end
end
defmacro by_day_of_week,
    do: quote do: %{unquote_splicing(days_of_week)}
```

It produces code:

```
"%{
  monday: fragment(\"count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)\", c.inserted_at(), 0),
  tuesday: fragment(\"count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)\", c.inserted_at(), 1), 
  wednesday: fragment(\"count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)\", c.inserted_at(), 2), 
  thursday: fragment(\"count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)\", c.inserted_at(), 3), 
  friday: fragment(\"count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)\", c.inserted_at(), 4), 
  saturday: fragment(\"count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)\", c.inserted_at(), 5), 
  sunday: fragment(\"count(extract(dow FROM ?) = ? OR null)\", c.inserted_at(), 6)
}"
```

And accordingly with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with macros you can probably do like that.

[Running example](http://elixirplayground.com?gist=847885e49d3dfb23872345789adab2f6)

```
defmodule MapUtils do
 defmacro spam(numbers) do
    quote do
      Enum.reduce(unquote(numbers), %{}, fn (elem, acc) -> 
        Map.put(acc, elem, elem)
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

Big thanks to Chris [Wende](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2086804/krzysztof-wende)